# Метод render перестраиваться бесконечное кол-во раз

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

начальный файл

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import List from "../../components/List";
import { getData } from "../../store/actions/getData";
import Spinner from "../../UI/Spinner/Spinner";

class ProductsArea extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.onGetProducts();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.props.products.length === 0) {
            return <Spinner />;
        }
        return <List isProducts = {this.props.products}/>;
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return  {
        products: state.prod
    }
};

const dispatchStateToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return  {
        onGetProducts: () => getData(dispatch)
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, dispatchStateToProps)(ProductsArea);


//метод getData

export function getData(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: actions.PRODUCTS_LOADING});
    axios.get("api/getData")
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: actions.GET_PROD_LIST,
                val: res.data
            });
        });
}
```

//List - тут метод Render выполняется бесконечное кол-во раз, данные успешно приходят

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Spinner from "../UI/Spinner/Spinner";

class List extends Component {

    state = {
        dataLoaded: false
    };

    dataLoadHandler = () => {
        this.setState({ dataLoaded: true });
    };


    render() {

        let result = <Spinner/>;
        const products = this.props.isProducts;

        console.log(products);

        if (products.length > 0) {
            this.dataLoadHandler();
        } 

        if (this.state.dataLoaded) {
            result = products.map(prod => {

                const primaryImgUrl = `img/product/mediam/${prod.PrimaryImg}`;
                const secondaryImgUrl = `img/product/mediam/${prod.SecondaryImg}`;

                const isNew = prod.New ? 
                (<div className="label_new">
                        <span className="new">new</span>
                    </div>) : null;

                const isSalePercent = prod.SalePercent != null ? 
                (<div className="sale-off">
                        <span className="sale-percent">-55%</span>
                    </div>) : null;

                return (<div className="single-product">
                    <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">

                        {isNew}

                        {isSalePercent}

                        <div className="product-img">
                            <a href="#">
                                <img className="primary-img" src={primaryImgUrl} alt="Product" />
                                <img className="secondary-img" src={secondaryImgUrl} alt="Product" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                        <div className="product-description">
                            <h5><a href="#">{prod.Name}</a></h5>
                            <div className="price-box">
                                <span className="price">$ {prod.Price}</span>
                                <span className="old-price">$ {prod.OldPrice}</span>
                            </div>
                            <p className="description">{prod.Description}</p>
                            <div className="product-action">
                                <div className="button-group">
                                    <div className="product-button">
                                        <button><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="product-button-2">
                                        <a onClick={this.openModalHandler} href="#" className="modal-view" id={
prod.ProductId} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal"
                                           title="Quickview"><i className="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>);
        });
    } 

    return (
        <div className="listview">
            {result}
        </div>  
    );
}
```

}

export default List;

Почему возникает такая ситуация, кто может объяснить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Старайтесь не делать `setState` внутри `render`

У вас 2 одинаковых условия: `products.length > 0` и `this.state.dataLoaded`

Когда у вас нет продуктов: `products.length > 0 === false` и `this.state.dataLoaded === false`

Когда есть продукты: `products.length > 0 === true` и `this.state.dataLoaded === true`

Получается что когда вы получили список продуктов, то вызывается функция `dataLoadHandler` внутри нее у вас `setState`, который вызывает перерисовку компонента. Поэтому у вас получается бесконечная перерисовка.

Вообще смысла в конструкции

```
if (products.length > 0) {
        this.dataLoadHandler();
}
```

для вашего компонента нет.

Перепишите свое условие

```
if (products.length > 0) {
    result = products.map(prod => {
           // тут ваш код скопируйте
           ...
    }
}
```

Тогда все будет в порядке.

UPD: можете просто поменять условия `this.state.dataLoaded` и `products.length > 0` местами, так тоже будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Все работает)

Comment: @СергейЧижик отметьте ответ как решение, пожалуйста:)